# JPA native query generation with COUNT (DISTINCT obj)

Tags: jpa, count, distinct, jpql

please help me with JPQL Query on OpenJPA 1.2.x
Here is the text of my query:

> select count (distinct evt) from Event
>   evt WHERE (evt.beginDate >=
>   :startOfPeriod and evt.beginDate <=
>   :endOfPeriod)  ORDER BY evt.beginDate
>   asc

At runtime I get an error:

> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException:
>   DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-119,
>   SQLSTATE=42803 , SQLERRMC=BEGIN_DATE,
>   DRIVER=3.59.81 {prepstmnt 1520523937
>   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.ID),
>   t0.BEGIN_DATE
>       FROM COMPANY.EVENT t0
>       WHERE (t0.BEGIN_DATE >= ? AND t0.BEGIN_DATE <= ?) optimize for 1 row
>   [params=(Timestamp) 2010-12-14
>   00:00:00.0, (Timestamp) 2010-12-14
>   23:59:59.999]} [code=-119,
>   state=42803]

Why does JPA prints field **t0.BEGIN_DATE** in select clause? 
Why did JPA miss ORDER BY clause in native SQL?
For example, this query (without t0.BEGIN_DATE in select clause) is valid:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t0.ID) 
    FROM CALENDAR.EVENT t0
    WHERE (t0.BEGIN_DATE >= null AND t0.BEGIN_DATE <= null)
```

*I've set null just for successful SQL query execution*

Is it a some kind of a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, man... just delete "ORDER BY evt.beginDate asc".
So stupid. I do count, I don't need order by...
Problem has been solved by myself. Excuse me for disturbing.